# General Relativity - perturbation in the metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor

This is part of a larger problem of trying to work through the derivation of Einstein's equations from the Einstein-Hilbert Action.

I want to show that if $g_{\mu \nu} \mapsto g_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu}$, then $$g^{\mu \nu} \mapsto g^{\mu \nu} - h^{\mu \nu}$$ where $g^{\mu \nu}$ are the components of the metric and $h^{\mu \nu}$ is a small perturbation.

The steps I understand are:

Let $g^{\mu \nu} \mapsto g^{\mu \nu} + \delta g^{\mu \nu}$.

Then use the definition: $(g^{\mu \alpha} + \delta g^{\mu \alpha})(g_{\alpha \nu} + h_{\alpha \nu}) = \delta^{\mu}_{\nu}$

Expanding gives $\delta^{\mu}_{\nu} + \delta g^{\mu \alpha}g_{\alpha \nu} + g^{\mu \alpha}h_{\alpha \nu} + ... = \delta^{\mu}_{\nu}$, ignoring higher order terms on the RHS.

> Now the part I am not too sure on is **why**: $$g^{\mu \alpha}h_{\alpha \nu} = h^{\mu}_{\nu}$$ $$\text{and}$$ $$\delta g^{\mu \alpha}g_{\alpha \nu} = \delta g^{\mu}_{\nu}$$

I can imagine as though the alpha's cancel to get one index upstairs and one index downstairs, but then by the same logic I can say $g^{\mu \alpha}h_{\alpha \nu} = g^{\mu}_{\nu}$, which I don't believe is necessary correct.

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g_{\alpha\beta}$ is a background metric. $h_{\alpha\beta}$ can not be used for raising and lowering indices. $h_{\alpha\beta}$ are simply perturbations. They are playing the role of tensors for manipulations(raising/lowering) with background metric $g_{\alpha\beta}$.